# ASP.NET Dropdownlist never select

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I had bound data into a dropdownlist from a json file and fill it.
But now, when I try to use the selected item with "dropdownlist.SelectedValue" it always returns the first row of the droplist and never let me get the other rows.

Follow the steps:

1:

```
Service1 s = new Service1();
string b = s.SelectProfile(_Default.id);
dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(b);
l_profile.DataSource = myObject;
l_profile.DataBind();
```

2:

```
Service1 s = new Service1();
int profile = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(l_profile.SelectedValue, @"\d+").Value);
```

Comment: please can you show add a sample of the json so that we may further help

Comment: Where are you using that 2nd bit of code? In an onclick function?

Comment: Did you wrap step 1 inside an `IsPostBack` check?

Comment: The Json file returns the id and description of profiles from the local database table. When I bind it into the dropdownlist I can select one of them.
Ex.:
first row: {"id": 1, "description":"ADM"}
second row: {"id": 2, "description":"USER"}

Comment: When I click a "Register" button, a function is called and get all information from textbox and dropdownlist. I already test it with fixed values and it worked, but with json file just the first row is selected.

Comment: I didn't wrap step 1. I can try it